# Array extension in Swift 3

Tags: swift3

The following filter method will return true if the elements in the array of Bool is all true.

```
print([false, true].filter({!$0}).isEmpty) // yields false
print([true, true].filter({!$0}).isEmpty)  // yields true
```

How do I create an extension method on the Array in Swift 3 that will allow me to represent it like this:

```
[false, true].allElementsTrue()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should answer your question:

```
extension Collection where Iterator.Element == Bool {

    var allElementsTrue: Bool {
        return self.filter({!$0}).isEmpty
    }

}
```

or

```
extension Collection where Iterator.Element == Bool {

    func allElementsTrue() -> Bool {
        return self.filter({!$0}).isEmpty
    }

}
```

But I prefer using computed properties when there's no parameter to give.

Note: as an alternative you could also `return !self.contains(false)` to get the same result more efficiently (short-circuiting).